# Multiple matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with 6 different figures within my code. I initialize them like this:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots()
fig5, ax5 = plt.subplots()
fig6, ax6 = plt.subplots()
```

Further I use the axes and figure objects for plotting graphs and saving them. Although the code works perfectly fine, I'd like to know if there is a better way to handle the situation (a more elegant approach). Is there something like collection of figures/axes objects available?

If indeed, such a collection is present, it would make life easy while setting, say, axes labels. One could run a loop through the collection objects and a list of labels I have prepared instead of defining each axes label individually. Any leads in the matter will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ash ...  we have to code it only.... you can keep the code handy and use it every time ... i end up opening and copy pasting the code from `https://plot.ly/matplotlib/subplots/`  .. i hope it helps

Comment: Can't you just store your figures and axes in lists?

Comment: @ThomasKühn excellent suggestion..Thank you!

Comment: @PuneetSinha Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very compact way to create several figures and axes and set some attributes would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figs, axs = zip(*[plt.subplots() for _ in range(6)])
plt.setp(axs, xlabel="My X Label")
plt.show()
```

This creates two iterables of figures and axes respectively, and sets the `xlabel` of all axes.